# From SQL to DQL

Tags: php, symfony, dql

I want to change this SQL query : (i'm using a bundle)
(Evenement is an entity and evenement_evenement is the result of self-referencing many to many of evenement)

```
SELECT * 
FROM   evenement e 
       natural JOIN evenement_evenement ee 
WHERE  e.id = ee.evenement_source 
       AND e.id = 3
```

Into DQL. For now I have this :

```
public function findAllEventAssociateByEvent($idEvent){
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('e');
    $qb->add('select', 'e');
    $qb->from('Bundle:Evenement', 'e2');
    $qb->where('e = :evenement');
    $qb->andWhere('e2 in e.evenements');
    $qb->setParameter('evenement', $idEvent);
    return $qb;
    //select * from evenement e NATURAL join evenement_evenement ee where e.id = ee.evenement_source and e.id = $idEvent
}
```

And i have this :

```
$eventAssocies = $em->getRepository('Bundle:Evenement')->findAllEventAssociateByEvent($id)->getQuery()->getResult();
```

But it's not working, i have an error in my "andWhere", but I don't know why...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL do DQL converting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48724916/sql-do-dql-converting)

Comment: What does "I have an error" mean? Is there any error message you forgot to share?

Comment: Yes, I've made some research, didn't help.
And my error for this code is : [Syntax Error] line 0, col 104: Error: Expected Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_OPEN_PARENTHESIS, got 'e'

Comment: could you please post your `evenement` entity class?

Answer (score 1):

I think you misunderstood some stuff, I reckon you query should more look like this:

```
public function findAllEventAssociateByEvent($idEvent){
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('e')
       ->join('e.evenement_evenement', 'e2')
       ->where('e = :evenement')
       ->setParameter('evenement', $idEvent);
    return $qb;
}
```

The join will do what you were trying to do with your `AndWhere` I reckon

Comment: I have this query with your code "SELECT e FROM Bundle\Entity\Evenement e INNER JOIN e.evenement e2 WHERE e = :evenement", i need both condition :/ 
And this error : [Semantical Error] line 0, col 69 near 'e2 WHERE e =': Error: Class Bundle\Entity\Evenement has no association named evenement

Comment: I assumed you have a related entity mapped by a field called `evenement` but you have to adapt to your situation.

Comment: Using join on your relating field will do your second condition `->join('e.relatingField, 'e2', 'WITH', 'e2.relatingField = id')` that's pretty much what it mean

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `andWhere` like that, you have to treat it like you treated your `where` clause. Declare a parameter, and later on, set it. From what I understand, you'd need to use a subquery for that `e.evenements` part. Whatever you expect to be in `e.evenements` part, extract it to a variable, e.g: `$evenements` and do the following:

```
$qb->andWhere('e2 IN (:evenements)')
   ->setParameter('evenements', $evenements, Doctrine\DBAL\Connection::PARAM_INT_ARRAY);
```

Assuming `$evenements` is an array. If it's a string, you can `explode()` it for example.

If you are looking for a quick solution, try this:

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('e')
           ->select('e.id')
           ->where('e.id = :evenement')
           ->setParameter('evenement', $idEvent);
 $evenementsIds = $qb->getQuery()->getResult(); // This will get you an array of ID's

$qb2 = $this->createQueryBuilder('e2')
            ->where('e2.id IN (:evenements)')
            ->setParameter('evenements', $evenementsIds, Doctrine\DBAL\Connection::PARAM_INT_ARRAY);

$result = $qb2->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Comment: What is result (what do you get) and what is a good result (what do you need to get)? Please, double check that you have something inside your database. Try to re-create query with a MySQL client to see whether you are actually querying with good parameters.

Comment: I get 1 result, but I need to have 2 results (i have to results in my database). I get 2 result in phpmyadmin with that : select * from evenement e NATURAL join evenement_evenement ee where e.id = ee.evenement_source and e.id = 1
where 1 is the id of 1 evenement

Comment: If that's the case, double check your parameters and database entries. I did my best with the DQL syntax and since you get 'something' I think your question, which was related to the error, is answered. Now what's going on with your parameters and results, I cannot tell you anything else without more details.

Comment: In my database : 
evenement : id, date... (with my entity Evenement)
evenement_evenement = evenement_origin, evenement_target (generated from entity Evenement with manytomany)

Comment: evenement and evenement_evenement are two tables in my database